# http: multiple response.WriteHeader calls

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, go

I am currently receiving this `http: multiple response.WriteHeader calls` error while trying to send back a response to Angular. The main thing I'm doing is sending a post request from Angular to Go. Go then inserts the data received into mongoDB, but if the username already exists I change `dup="true"` and try to send a custom response.

```
func Register(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {

u := req.FormValue("username")
p := req.FormValue("password")
e := req.FormValue("email")
n := req.FormValue("name")

err := tpl.ExecuteTemplate(w, "index.html", User{u, p, e, n})
if err != nil {
    http.Error(w, err.Error(), 500)
    log.Fatalln(err)
}

a := User{Username: u, Password: p, Email: e, Name: n}
if a.Username != "" || a.Password != "" || a.Email != "" || a.Name != "" {
    insert(a)
    if dup == "true" {
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
    }
}}
```

`w.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)` is just an example; if I use anything with write header I get the same `http: multiple response.WriteHeader calls`

Comment: `ExecuteTemplate` writes a response; you can't write another response header after that if `dup == "true"`. You also don't want to use `log.Fatal` in a web server, since a single request error could crash the server.

Answer (score 3):

This line `err := tpl.ExecuteTemplate(w, "index.html", User{u, p, e, n})` should be the last thing you do since it will write to your response.

If you want to handle any potential errors that you may encounter when you render `index.html` you can render the template by passing in a `bytes.Buffer`

```
buf := &bytes.Buffer{}
if err := tpl.ExecuteTemplate(buf, "index.html", User{u, p, e, n}); err != nil {
    log.Printf("Error rendering 'index.html' - error: %v", err)
    http.Error(w, "Internal Server Error", 500)
    return
}

// Write your rendered template to the ResponseWriter
w.Write(buf.Bytes())
```